# Responsiive NavBar Z-Index

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, z-index

I'm 2 days trying to make responsive navbar but I have problem with making full width element that is `relative` positioned with `z-index`.

I have this HTML code:

```
<ul class="navigation pull-right">
  <li><a href="/index/">HOME</a>
  <li><a href="/category/news/">NOVOSTI</a></li>
  <li><a href="/category/html/">HTML</a></li>
  <li><a href="/category/css/">CSS</a></li>
  <li><a href="/category/php/">PHP</a></li>
  <li><a href="/contact/">KONTAKT</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is general CSS for all screen widths:

```
.header > .navbar > .navigation {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.header > .navbar > .navigation > li {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

And this code for screens smaller than 720px:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .header > .navbar > .navigation {
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 200;
  }

  .header > .navbar > .navigation > li {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    background-color: #424242;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #848484;
  }
}
```

Now when I open site on mobile phone with display smaller than 720px or resize browser I'm getting this result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HS75u.png

But I want to make navbar full width without empty space on left side. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried setting the margin and padding on the UL to 0? `ul { margin:;padding:0 }`

Comment: When I set `padding` and `margin` on UL to 0 it partly sloves problem http://prntscr.com/8i2v2i

Comment: now in your `@media` rule set `.header > .navbar > .navigation > li { margin-left:0; padding-left:20px}`

Comment: Oh, how I'm stupid. Thanks a lot!